# Frustrating Sqlite3 Database is locked error

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

i am using sqlite3 for a c# .net4.5 win form application.i observe that while using UPDATE query on a table i am encountering database is locked error on the other hand SELECT query on the same table does not give any errors.why is it so?

> ```
>                 //qryStrUQMFR = "SELECT * FROM loc_table_1 WHERE t_id =@t_id AND mem_id =@mem_id";
>                 qryStrUQMFR = "UPDATE loc_ loc_table_1 SET field1=@field1, field2=@field2, field3 =@field3, field4 =@field4 WHERE t_id =@t_id AND mem_id =@mem_id";
> ```

```
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conMRN = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conMRN.Open();
                using (SQLiteTransaction tranMRN = conMRN.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmdMRN = new SQLiteCommand(qryStrUQMFR, conMRN))
                    {
                        cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@t_id", DbType.Int32).Value = t_id;
                        cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@mem_id", DbType.Int32).Value = mem_id;
            cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@field1", DbType.Int32).Value = selAns;
                        cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@field2", DbType.Int32).Value = qa;
                        cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@field3", DbType.Int32).Value = qna;
                        cmdMRN.Parameters.Add("@field4", DbType.Int32).Value = qm;
                        cmdMRN.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (SQLiteDataReader rdrMRN = cmdMRN.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (rdrMRN != null && rdrMRN.Read())
                            {
                //more code here                            
                            }
                        }// reader closed and disposed up here
                    }// command disposed here
                    tranMRN.Commit();
                }
            } //connection closed and disposed here
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("mrn-->" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Are you aware of how many simultaneous queries are runnings against that sqlite file?  Something may have a read lock open, which would allow other reads but not writes.

Comment: yes maybe 3 queries are running against that file

Comment: I'm not particularly experienced with sqlite but since it's serverless, your client might have to do the retry logic to support simultaneous transactions itself.   You may want to move to a more industrial strength db such as MySQL or postgres, both are free and are server client models which will handle transaction isolation better.

Comment: yes you are right @Dan regarding moving onto industrial strength db.Can you suggest some free db's which could be included in the setup of my c# projects.